# react-redux project. Chrome dev tools does not show all projects files

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create react-redux app. During debugging Chrome dev tools does not show all the files. Actions and containers folders dissapeared. I can see them  in VS code but not in Chrome dev tools. The base of my app is create-react-app. What is wrong? I have created new app just to check and I cannot add any new folder or file to the src folder. [image]

Comment: Add more details, screenshot, code or something. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @Lucas Thank you for your answer, probably it is some kind of newbe mistake but I'm lost. I've updated vs code, resetted chrome and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple things to do.

1. reset to default to make sure nothing is because of settings (F1 while in dev tools to open settings):

[image]

2. Go to network tab and refresh the page, then switch to sources.
   [image]
3. Your IDE is showing more files because it shows all files and your dev tools shows only files used to load the site